# Display comments to the page

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a problem posting comments on the page depending on the posting id.

Controller:

```
 public function viewUserQuestion(Post $post) { 
    $comment = Comment::where('post_id', $post->id)->get();
    return view('viewQuestion', compact('post','comment'));
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/viewUserQuestion/{post}', 'PostsController@viewUserQuestion')->name('viewQuestion');
```

View:

```
 @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
                        <span class="m-b-15 d-block" align="center">
                            {!! $comment->commentText !!}
                        </span> 
 @endforeach
```

What do you think will be the problem? Do you think I'm making the wrong display or?

Comment: _I have a problem posting comments on the page_ **What problem**. I have a problem is really not any help to us helping you. Please tell us What Problem you have

Comment: 1. rename `comment` to `comments` in controller 2.  In view change `$post->comments` to `$comments`

Answer (score 0):

at this side

change

```
return view('viewQuestion', compact('post','comment'));
```

to

```
return view('viewQuestion', ['comment'=>$comment]);
```

and change the view to

```
 @foreach($comment as $comment)
                    <span class="m-b-15 d-block" align="center">
                        {!! $comment->commentText !!}
                    </span> 
 @endforeach
```

hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below it will work perfectly.

Controller:

```
public function viewUserQuestion(Post $post) { 
    $comments = Comment::where('post_id', $post->id)->get();
    return view('viewQuestion', compact('comments'));
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
    <span class="m-b-15 d-block" align="center">
        {!! $comment->commentText !!}
    </span> 
 @endforeach
```